# How to reformat code on save in RubyMine?

Tags: rubymine

Is there a way to automatically reformat my code when I Save All (cmd+s) on Mac RubyMine?

I tried to bind the shortcut CMD + S to both Save All and Reformat Code but that didn't do the trick.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Try recording a macro that involves reformatting your code and assigning a new keyboard shortcut to it.

1. First go to to Edit -> Macros -> Start Macro Recording.
   A small green box should appear at the bottom right-hand corner - Macro recording started...
2. Go to Code -> Reformat Code.
3. Go to File -> Save All.
4. Go to Edit -> Macros -> Stop Macro Recording.
5. Name your macro (e.g. *reformat on save*)
6. Go to RubyMine -> Preferences -> Keymap and look for your macro (e.g. *reformat on save*) in the search box at the top right-hand corner.
7. Right-click your macro and *Add Keyboard Shortcut*.
8. Go with cmd + s or cntrl + s and override the existing one.
9. Click Apply and OK.

Answer (score 3):

You can now do this with the latest RubyMine. Go to preferences -> Tools -> Actions on Save.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to reformat on save that I know of. However, you can tell RubyMine to reformat before committing by checking the appropriate checkbox in the Commit Changes dialog. Not that I would do that myself -- if someone misformatted a file and I then changed one line, I wouldn't want my commit to include all the reformatting.